# How do I include an OCaml module that is not called from the main module in an executable with dune?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I want to include a module in an OCaml program where the module is not
directly called by the main (or any other) module, but rather does something during
initialization.  How do I do that with `dune`?  It seems that `dune`
only includes modules that are explicitly invoked, even when I list
other modules in a `modules` stanza.

### Example of `dune` not doing what I want:

`Mod1.ml`:

```
let mod1 () : unit =
  Printf.printf "in mod1\n"

let () =
  mod1 ()
```

`Mod2.ml`:

```
let mod2 () : unit =
  Printf.printf "in mod2\n"

let () =
  mod2 ()
```

`dune`:

```
(executable
  (name Mod1)
  (modules
    Mod1
    Mod2
  )
)
```

`dune-project`

```
(lang dune 3.3)
```

Compiling and running:

```
$ dune exec ./Mod1.exe
in mod1
```

My goal is to also see `in mod2` above output.

### Example that works with direct `ocamlc` invocation:

This is what I would do if not using `dune`:

```
$ ocamlc -o both.exe Mod1.ml Mod2.ml
$ ./both.exe
in mod1
in mod2
```

### Adding an explicit call

If I change `Mod1.ml` to:

```
let mod1 () : unit =
  Printf.printf "in mod1\n"

let () =
  mod1 ();
  Mod2.mod2 ()    (* added *)
```

Then both modules get included:

```
$ dune exec ./Mod1.exe
in mod2
in mod1
in mod2
```

But my goal is include `Mod2` in the executable without explicitly
invoking it from `Mod1`.

### `empty_module_interface_if_absent` does not help

In the documentation for the
[`executable`](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html#executable-1)
stanza, it says:

> `(empty_module_interface_if_absent)` causes the generation of empty
> interfaces for every module that does not have an interface file
> already. Useful when modules are used solely for their side-effects.
> This field is available since the 3.0 version of the Dune language.

However, this does not help.  With `dune` file:

```
(executable
  (name Mod1)
  (empty_module_interface_if_absent)   ; added
  (modules
    Mod1
    Mod2
  )
)
```

and reverting to the original `Mod1.ml`, the behavior is the same:

```
$ dune exec ./Mod1.exe
in mod1
```

### Versions, etc.

```
$ ocamlc --version
4.14.0

$ dune --version
3.3.1

$ opam --version
2.1.2

$ uname -a
Linux mint201vm 5.4.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 08:16:25 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pack your modules in a library and then link this library to your main executable using the `linkall` option. E.g., using your concrete example,

```
(executable
 (name mod1)
 (modules mod1)
 (libraries libmod2)
 (flags -linkall))

(library
 (name libmod2)
 (modules mod2))
```

But it is more convenient to pack all modules into a library and move the executable into a separate folder. You can create an empty file for the executable main module or do some initialization in it, e.g.,

```
$ tree
.
├── dune
├── dune-project
├── mod1.ml
├── mod2.ml
└── run
    ├── dune
    └── main.ml
$ cat dune
(library
 (name impl))

$ cat run/dune
(executable
 (name main)
 (libraries impl)
 (flags -linkall))

$ dune exec ./run/main.exe
in mod2
in mod1
```

Either way, note that by default dune packs modules in a library to prevent name-clashing with other libraries (since OCaml has a flat namespace for compilation units). Therefore to access a module `Mod2` in the library `Libmod2` you have to say `Libmod2.Mod2` (if you're outside of the library). If you want to disable this packing, use `(wrapped false)` in the `library` stanza.

Comment: This is not a problem, but the expected behavior. Dune wraps by default your libraries in a top-level module that has the same name as the library, so to access a module named `bar` in a library `foo` you have to write `Foo.Bar`. You can disable wrapping, but it is not recommended and should be used only when you porting to dune existing projects that do some kind of wrapping manually. See the documentation link provided below
https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html?highlight=wrapped#library-1

Comment: Thanks for the further update.  I made a few small suggested tweaks (which of course you're free to reject or modify).